# AES Encryption with ASCII string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ascii, aes

I am encrypting the following XML request with AES algorithm , but while decrypting some value got truncated at the end

```
This is my data : <Xml><req1><sub1>120739</sub1><sub2>11</sub2><sub3>111</sub3><sub4>100201</sub4><sub5>102001</sub5><sub6>513582</sub6><sub7>103140</sub7><sub8>ONE</sub8></req1><req2><sub9>11</sub9><sub10>11</sub10><sub11>13</sub11><sub12>4427808003414523777</sub12><sub13>�����&Ôy3ë    ÷ ���\�6Cÿ�'�4� ���64701244 3àøÈ@5"BÀ���_*@A�����7awO ���</sub13><sub14>100.00</sub14></req2></Xml>
```

I am using following method to encrypt and decrypt :

```
+(NSData*)AESCrypto :(char *)key :(char*)dataIn :(CCOperation)CryptOperation :(int)inlength :(CCAlgorithm)type :(size_t)keysize :(CCOptions)mode
{

char dataOut[inlength + kCCKeySizeAES128];
bzero(dataOut, sizeof(dataOut));
size_t numBytesEncryptedorDecrypted=0;
char iv[16]={0};
CCCryptorStatus result =CCCrypt(CryptOperation,type,mode,key,keysize,iv,dataIn,inlength, dataOut, sizeof(dataOut), &numBytesEncryptedorDecrypted);
NSLog(@"CryptoStatus:%d",result);

NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:dataOut length:numBytesEncryptedorDecrypted];

return data;
}
```

Can any one tell me the problem why some characters got truncated at the end after decryption , any solution is there to solve this ?

Comment: Can you tell us the options used such as mode and padding?

Comment: It looks like you have invalid data in the XML, only unicode characters are allowed, not raw data. The contents of `sub13` do not appear to be unicode.

Answer (score 1):

This one is good example of AES Encryption & Decryption

https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor

Just add the class in your workspace and call the API of it.

Comment: That is rather old and hasn't been updated in five years.